# What is the difference between ansible's remote_user & become_user

Tags: ansible, privileges, elevated-privileges

I need to understand the difference between ansible's remote_user & become_user considering that the play will either run locally or remotely.

Difference between:

```
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: user1

- hosts: all
  remote_user: user1
```

Will there be any difference incase ssh keys are setup between the servers ?

I tried to google for the differences but did not find any good explanation for the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Q: ***"Will there be any difference in case SSH keys are set up between the servers?"***

A: There will be no difference in [privilege](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation) between

```yaml
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: user1
```

and

```yaml
- hosts: all
  remote_user: user1
  become: no
```

There might be a difference in the [environment](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#may-not-access-environment-variables-populated-by-pamd-systemd) set for  *user1* between:

- privilege escalation, e.g. *`sudo user1`* and
- ssh connection to *`user1@host`*.

Notes:

- The best practice is not to allow ssh to *root*
- In most cases, [*become_user*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#become-directives) is *root* (this is also default)
- In most cases, two steps are needed:

  1. Connect to *remote_user@host* and
  2. Escalate privilege to *root* (*become: yes*).
- See [Risks of becoming an unprivileged user](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user).

Answer (score 8):

- The become_user means the user that will execute the playbook, and the remote user will execute it on the remote servers.
- become: yes which will do a sudo to root automatically by default.  But then you told it the remote_user: deployer which told the server that the user logging in is deployer and after they log in do the default sudo.

There are stable differences:

- become:yes  = . Use sudo and be root by default
- become_user: user1 = Using sudo from become:yes and becoming user user1.
- remote_user: user1 = Log in as foofoo on that remote server.